# VBA EXCEL Range syntax

Tags: vba, excel

I don't understand syntax for range.

Why does this work:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Copy
Next
```

But this doesn't work:

```
For i = 2 To lastRow
    num = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(i, 1), Range("A" & lastRow), 0)
 Next
```

Why do I need to use

```
For i = 2 To lastRow
    'num = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(i, 1), Range("A1:A" & lastRow), 0)
Next
```

What A1:A mean? Why can't I use

```
Range("A" & lastRow), 0
```

Comment: You're specifying the start and end cells for a range - "A1:A" isn't what you're using, but "A1:A3" to express a range - a single cell range could just be "A1:A1", etc.

Comment: OK, that makes sense for second line, but the syntax for first seems odd.

Comment: I went ahead and posted an answer that tried to explain this in a bit more detail. Hopefully that will help :)

Comment: It would read easier as Range("A" & i  ":" & "D" & i) or Range("A" & i  & ":" & "D" & i) but the compiler wants that certain format, so I just have to refer to this thread instead of thinking!.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Might vote it up if you found it helpful :)

Comment: Very helpful, but I just joined so I can't upvote.  :(

Comment: LOL no problem...just pick it as answer :) Have an awesome day :)

Comment: The [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) is expecting an array of cells in its *lookup_array* parameter. `=MATCH(A1, A1, 0)` works on a worksheet due the error control overhead assuming *'close enough'*. It isn't working in VBA because the bar for correct syntax is a bit higher. Use `num = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(i, 1), Array(Range("A" & lastRow)), 0)` to tell it explicitly that you are passing an array of one cell into the *lookup_array* parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your syntax and your code should've work just fine.
The problem with using worksheet function like `Match`, `Vlookup` and other look up functions is that if the value being searched is not found, it throws up an error.

In your case, you are trying to search multiple values in just one cell.
So let us say your `lastrow` is 9. You're code will loop from `Cell(2,1)` to `Cell(9,1)` checking if it is within `Range("A" & lastrow)` or `Range("A9")`.

If your values from `Cell(2,1)` through `Cell(9,1)` is the same as your value in `Range("A9")`, you won't get an error.

Now, if you use `Range("A1:A" & lastrow)`, it will surely work cause you are trying to match every  element of that said range to itself and surely a match will be found.

```
WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(2,1), Range("A1:A9")) 'will return 2
WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(3,1), Range("A1:A9")) 'will return 3
'
'
'And so on if all elements are unique
```

It doesn't matter if you use `Range("A9")` or `Range("A1:A9")`.
What matters is that you handle the error in case you did not find a match.
One way is to use `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Goto 0` like this:

```
Sub ject()
    Dim num As Variant
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long: lastrow = 9

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        On Error Resume Next
        num = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(i, 1), Range("A" & lastrow), 0)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then num = "Not Found"
        On Error GoTo 0
        Debug.Print num
    Next
End Sub
```

Another way is to use `Application.Match` over `WorksheetFunction.Match` like this:

```
Sub ject()
    Dim num As Variant
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long: lastrow = 9

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        num = Application.Match(Cells(i, 1), Range("A" & lastrow), 0)
        Debug.Print num
        'If Not IsError(num) Then Debug.Print num Else Debug.Print "Not Found"
    Next
End Sub
```

`Application.Match` works the same way but it doesn't error out when it returns `#N/A`. So you can assign it's value in a `Variant` variable and use it later in the code without any problem. Better yet, use `IsError` test to check if a value is not found as seen above in the commented lines.

In both cases above, I used a `Variant` type `num` variable.
Main reason is for it to handle any other value if in case no match is found.

As for the Range Syntax, don't be confused, it is fairly simple.
Refer to below examples.

1. Single Cell - All refer to *A1*

   ```
   Cells(1,1) ' Using Cell property where you indicate row and column
   Cells(1) ' Using cell property but using just the cell index
   Range("A1") ' Omits the optional [Cell2] argument
   ```

   Don't be confused with using cell index. It is like you are numbering all cells from left to right, top to bottom.
   [image]

   ```
   Cells(16385) ' refer to A2
   ```
2. Range of contiguous cell - All refer to A1:A10

   ```
   Range("A1:A10") ' Classic
   Range("A1", "A10") ' or below
   Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 1))
   ```

   Above uses the same syntax `Range(Cell1,[Cell2])` wherein the first one, omits the `optional` argument `[Cell2]`. And because of that, below also works:

   ```
   Range("A1:A5","A6:A10")
   Range("A1", "A8:A10")
   Range("A1:A2", "A10")
   ```
3. Non-Contiguous cells - All refer to A1, A3, A5, A7, A9

   ```
   Range("A1,A3,A5,A7,A9") ' Classic
   ```

Comment: I obviously stand corrected. I didn't realize my Excel VBA was quite that rusty. Errant answer deleted.

Comment: Thanks! Range("A1", "A" & lastRow), 0) works to look in range (A1 to A9) with lastrow=9.  MUCH easier to read than Range("A1:A" & lastRow), 0)

Comment: L42, very thorough answer, much more than I was expecting.  Hopefully this will help others.

Answer (score 1):

Without any specific details about the error, I assume that Match does not return the value you expect, but rather an #N/A error. Match has the syntax

=match(lookup_value, lookup_range, match_type)

The lookup_range typically consists of a range of several cells, either a column with several rows or a row with several columns.

In your formula, you have only one cell in the lookup_range. Let's say Lastrow is 10. The first three runs of the loop produce the formula

```
=Match(A2,A10,0)
=Match(A3,A10,0)
=Match(A4,A10,0)
```

It is a valid formula but in most cases the result won't be a match but an error. Whereas what you probably want is

```
=Match(A2,A1:A10,0)
```

Looking again at your code, stitch it together and find why you need `A1:A` as a string constant in your formula:

```
For i = 2 To lastRow
    num = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(i, 1), Range("A1:A" & lastRow), 0)
Next
```

Comment: num = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(i, 1), Range("A" & lastRow), 0)
gives Run-time error 1004.  Unable to get the match property of the Worksheet function class.  You are correct that I was looking for A1:A10, just didn't understand the syntax