# I cannot figure out why my copy and paste is not working VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been sitting for a while trying to figure out why this code isnt working.

```
With PTrend

    If Range("P3") > 0 Then
        .Range("E3" & .Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
        .Range("D3:D" & .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    End If

End With
```

I am trying to copy the range E3 to the last row of P and paste the special values starting in D3. For some reason, it is taking cell E30 and using that value as all the values to copy and paste

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

G

Comment: Remove the `()` around `xlPasteValues`

Comment: And change `"E3"` to `"E3:E"`

Comment: @ScottCraner that also needs a `.Row` if the OP wants a single column copied, but I think they want `Range("E3",.Range("P" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` to get multiple columns

Comment: Which cells are you trying to copy - something like E3:E456?  Or something like E3:P456?

Comment: If you just need values, you could do `.Range("D3:D" & .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value = .Range("E3:E" & .Range("P" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value`  Assuming you mean to copy column E data, and not `E:P`  ...even if that's not truly right, just set the ranges' values equal to eachother, it is faster and avoids using the clipboard.

Comment: And does column C and column P always have the same number of rows populated?

Comment: I made a post regarding [Range Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30406676/2685412) before and I think this will help you. Now, on top of what Scott and YowE3k said (and Bruce), make sure you reference all your objects explicitly when you use `With Clause` by preceding all objects associated to the worksheet with a dot. Also, you shouldn't be using `&` but a comma `,` instead in your copy line.

Comment: @YowE3K, yes, I am trying to copy a range like E3:P456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your code using your current methodology:

```
With PTrend
    If .Range("P3").Value > 0 Then
        .Range("E3", .Range("P" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
        .Range("D3:D" & .Range("P" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If    
End With
```