# VBA Range using a variable to set a location

Tags: vba, excel

I want to have my program begin a count at a specific location defined by a variable.  I know that you can use `rn = sh.Cells(9, 1)` for example, and the variable `rn` is now holding the location of `cells(9,1)`.  But when I use the variable `rn` in my count command, I am getting the following error:

> Method 'Range' of object' _worksheet' failed

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Struc_Equa()
Dim n As Integer

End sub
Sub countN(n)

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rn As Range
Dim SheNa As String
SheNa = ActiveSheet.Name
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheNa)

Set rn = sh.Cells(9, 1)

' The command below does not work
'n = sh.Range(rn, sh.Range(rn).End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count

' I am able to do what I want but in a inefficient way (shown below)
'n = sh.Range("A9", sh.Range("A9").End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
rn.Activate
 MsgBox (n)

End Sub
```

Why is this error happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
n = sh.Range(rn, rn.End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
```

It follows the *Range([Cell1],[Cell2])* syntax.
Remember that `rn` is already a fully referenced range address so you can use it directly as arguments to *Range* object. More about [Range Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30406676/2685412).

Why does your original code fail?

Because based on [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel), in *Range(arg)* syntax, *arg* names the range.
And take note that *Range Object*'s default property is `Value`.
So your code:

```
sh.Range(rn).End(xlToRight)
```

is actually evaluating the value of `rn` and supplies it as *arg* for the *Range(arg)* syntax. If the value of that cell is not a valid cell or range address (or name as the article mentioned), it will throw an error. Above actually evaluates like below:

```
sh.Range("value from rn range object").End(xlToRight)
```

If you try changing the value of that cell with a valid cell or range name/address, it will work. For example:

```
With sh
    Set rn = .Cells(9, 1)
    rn.Value2 = "A9"
    n = .Range(rn, .Range(rn).End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
    MsgBox n
End With
```

In short:

1. *Range(arg)* expects a valid range name or address.
2. *Range([cell1],[cell2])* expects a valid range object reference.

Comment: This was exactly the issue.  Can you explain further what was wrong with the the original code?

Comment: @MaxHollander See my update. I hope it is clearer now. ;)

Comment: Do you have much experiance with C++ i have a few questions regarding it  ability etc

Comment: @LA_MAR2 No, I am not well versed in C++ but you can post your question here and I'm sure there are a lot of gurus here.